# Google Sheets query output changes upon closing and reopening workbook

Tags: google-sheets, refresh, textjoin

I have a workbook where I track game stats for my local community. I added a chart that changes upon a few selections and I use `filter` to get the desired result. The data comes from a sheet where I use `query` to calculate month to month differences (since I could not find this easily done with google's provided pivot options). One of the query's looks like this

`=query('Response Edits'!1:1112,"select A,B,C WHERE A IS NOT NULL AND NOT H matches '"&textjoin("|",TRUE,query('Response Edits'!1:1112,"select min(H) WHERE A IS NOT NULL group by D",0))&"' order by D, C ASC",0)`

- **A** converts the month value in the timestamp to the correct survey month (e.g. a 2020-07-01 would be for 06 survey and 2020-07-29 would
  be for 07 survey)
- **B** converts the year value in the timestamp to the correct survey year
- **C** is the timestamp of the survey submission
- **D** is the player name
- **H** is the player XP of the survey submission (I use this as a lazy solution since it only increases and because I could not figure out a
  way to include the key phrase *date* using multiple  datetime e.g.
  `NOT C matches date texjoin("|",TRUE,"select min(C)...")` did not work)

the textjoin is just to remove the earliest date submitted because it would not have a month to month value. Here is a portion of the output of the query above and another query which I believe is correct:

```
7   2020    2020-07-31 23:18:48 ... 6873449 198 11610
8   2020    2020-08-31 22:15:53 ... 7789713 175 8732
9   2020    2020-09-30 23:03:12 ... 5994347 139 8932
```

When I close the the sheet and reopen it I notice that my chart has only 0 values because my sheet with the query functions is only outputting 0. The above query and my other query have also given a different output, which I have provided a portion for below:

```
6   2020    2020-06-30 22:04:02 ... 0   0   0
7   2020    2020-07-31 23:18:48 ... 0   0   0
8   2020    2020-08-31 22:15:53 ... 0   0   0
9   2020    2020-09-30 23:03:12 ... 0   0   0
```

I am new to using query, but the formula seems correct, because if I change the last 0 in the formula (which is the option for header) to 1 and then back to 0 I get the desired result.

Tl;dr Why does the queried data not output correctly when I close and reopen a workbook? And why does it output correctly after the formula is changed and changed back (including selecting undo)? Is it potentially `textjoin` or `matches` causing the problem in the query?

Answer (score 0):

try to run this:

```
=QUERY('Response Edits'!A1:H1112,
 "select A,B,C 
  where A is not null 
    and not H matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, 
 QUERY('Response Edits'!A1:H1112,
 "select min(H) 
  where A is not null group by D", 0))&"'
  order by D, C", 0)
```

Comment: Same problem. Is the thought that the query is trying to pick from too much? If so then it would be my other query causing the problem since it must output most, but not all columns.

Comment: @user75667 can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: do you want the whole workbook, specifically the sheet in question, or the sheet in question plus the sheets it is tied to?

Comment: @user75667 `Response Edits` sheet would be enough I guess. up to you